# NSURLRequest isEqual: affected by allHTTPHeaderFields

Tags: foundation

I compare two NSURLRequest objects which URL and header are same, but `isEqual:` return `NO`, so debug:

when I `po [taskRequest isEqual:request]` result is `NO`, `po request.allHTTPHeaderFields` to check is equal, then `po [taskRequest isEqual:request]` result is `YES`️

I found if use `addValue:forHTTPHeaderField:` instead of `setValue:forHTTPHeaderField:`, it always return `YES`

I try verify in playground *Xcode Version 10.2 (10E125)*:

```swift
let request1 = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.abc.com")!)
let request2 = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.abc.com")!)

request1.setValue("1", forHTTPHeaderField: "1")
request2.setValue("1", forHTTPHeaderField: "1")

request1 == request2 // true

request2.allHTTPHeaderFields // ["1": "1"]

request1 == request2 // false
```

I expect isEqual: result always correct no matter if I have used the `allHTTPHeaderFields` method

Comment: I have checked in Objective-c it works as expected. NSMutableURLRequest responds correctly to `isEqual:`. Note that when printing out `request1 == request2` you are not comparing the requests, but their memory addresses. Always use `isEqual:` to find out if they are really equal or not.

Comment: @Mr.Zystem `request1 == request2` is swift code